# How can I get this timestamp format with javascript / jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get this format :

`2019-03-24 15:05:20`

Here is what I have tried:

```
var today = new Date();
var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var dateTime = date+' '+time;
```

I got:

`2019-3-24 15:0:20`

It's missing leading zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

That's because numbers lower than 10 should be padded with zero but they aren't.

You can use `padStart` function to achieve the expected result - add a leading 0 character if the length of a number is less than 2. I modified your code a little bit but all you need is to use `.toString().padStart(2, '0')` on a number.

```js
var today = new Date();

var date = [
  today.getFullYear(),
  today.getMonth() + 1,
  today.getDate(),
].map((value) => value.toString().padStart(2, '0')).join('-');

var time = [
  today.getHours(),
  today.getMinutes(),
  today.getSeconds(),
].map((value) => value.toString().padStart(2, '0')).join(':');;


var dateTime = date + ' ' + time;
console.log(dateTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty close to ISO 8601, so let's start with that.

```
const d = new Date();
d
  .toISOString() // Convert date to a string in the format of 2019-03-25T00:07:22.0253Z
  .substr(0, 19)  // Strip off the milliseconds and Zulu timezone indication
  .replace('T', ' '); // Replace the T for "time" with a space
```

This leaves you with a date formatted like `2019-03-25 00:07:22`.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  It's a perfectly reasonable solution to the problem presented, and is well documented.  I really don't understand Stack Overflow these days.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operation for simple use. This should give you leading zero.

```
        var today = new Date();
        var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
        var time = today.getHours() + ":" + (today.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
        var dateTime = date + ' ' + time;

        console.log(dateTime, 'result');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var d = new Date();
d = new Date(d.getTime() - 3000000);
var date_format_str = d.getFullYear().toString()+"-"+((d.getMonth()+1).toString().length==2?(d.getMonth()+1).toString():"0"+(d.getMonth()+1).toString())+"-"+(d.getDate().toString().length==2?d.getDate().toString():"0"+d.getDate().toString())+" "+(d.getHours().toString().length==2?d.getHours().toString():"0"+d.getHours().toString())+":"+((parseInt(d.getMinutes()/5)*5).toString().length==2?(parseInt(d.getMinutes()/5)*5).toString():"0"+(parseInt(d.getMinutes()/5)*5).toString())+":00";
console.log(date_format_str);
```